“process is not defined” error when loading remote module in Angular 17 host app and Angular 14 remote app with Module Federation
Question:
I’m encountering a process is not defined error when I try to load a remote Angular module via Module Federation in my Angular 17 host app. The remote app is using Angular 14. I'm using Module Federation with the @angular-architects/module-federation package and Webpack to dynamically load remote modules, but when I try to load the remoteEntry.js, I get the following error:
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at 94655 (util.js:109:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 50372 (checks.js:6:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 14430 (index.js:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 89236 (backoff.js:5:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 42215 (index.js:4:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)

Details:

Host Angular Version: 17

Remote Angular Version: 14

Module Federation Package: @angular-architects/module-federation

Polyfills Configuration: I have polyfills.ts correctly set up to include the process polyfill (import 'process/browser';), but I’m still seeing the error.

Configuration Files:
Webpack configuration in the remote app (webpack.config.js):
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "auto", 
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'remoteApp',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './AppModule': './src/app/app.module.ts',
      },
      shared: {
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Routing configuration in the host app (app-routing.module.ts):
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'mfe1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './AppModule',
      }).then(m => m.AppModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}



What I’ve Tried:

Added import 'process/browser'; to polyfills.ts.
Ensured remoteEntry.js is being served correctly (verified by accessing http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js).
Used webpack.ProvidePlugin in the Webpack configuration to polyfill process but the error still persists.

Error Details:

The error occurs when attempting to load the remote module in the host application at http://localhost:4200/mfe1.
I verified that remoteEntry.js is accessible, but still getting the process is not defined error.

What am I missing?

What am I doing wrong? Why am I still encountering the process is not defined error even after adding polyfills and ensuring the correct configuration for the remote module?


